# Display Correct Modified By and Modified times and dates using Powershell

Tags: powershell, version-history, csv

I have a script that outputs to CSV all items from all Lists and all files from all Libraries below:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
#$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts3/HBG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {


foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = ($item["Created"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = ($item["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
                        "Item Name" = $item.Name

}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
#$site.Dispose()
}




Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\GenerateReport.csv
```

Below is a sample output of the script:

[image]

Displayed above is a file (Lions.pdf) with 3 versions total. Version 3 is the current version of the file and the data for Modified By and Modified Date displays correct as Doe, Jane.

When I go to Version History I see a problem:

- For **Version 2** of the file it was Modified By **Parayno,
  Frank** with a Modified Date of **10/25/11 5:15 PM**
- For **Version 1** of the file it was Modified By **Doe, John** with a Modified Date of **6/28/11 11:23 AM**.

The script seems to populate the previous versions with the most current user who modified the file, in this case, Doe, Jane. Also, for the column Modified Date, it is displaying the same date/time from Version 3 to Version 2 and 1. What can I do to the script to display the correct user and date/time for the columns Modified By and Modified Date? Can someone please assist?

Below is the **desired output** of the script:

[image]

Comment: curious to know where u run this command from? is it the PowerShell within the SharePoint server ?!  I am running on my PC and I get message Get-SPWeb is not recognised

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing it is because of this section:

```
 "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
 "Modified Date" = ($item["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
```

In reality, you should be using $version to get to the version history of the item. You are iterating over each version of the item, yet you are referencing the item properties. Something like:

```
"Modified By" = $version["Editor"]
 "Modified Date" = ($version["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it sort of works. The output with the suggested changes is displayed here: https://plus.google.com/101260755580272499158/posts/YyH9tDfXmo4?pid=6212661280373656642&oid=101260755580272499158&authkey=CJjXjJ2NrsLGWw. Essentially the Modified By looks like it is displaying the user's email and such. As far as the Modified Date it is displaying the time 5hrs ahead. Could you please assist? Also not sure how to add an image to comments hence the link. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using $item["Modified"] to get the modified date of the version  - I think you need to use $version["Modified"] or else it will just continue to use the modified date of the current, latest version. Same for the rest of the fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it sort of works. The output with the suggested changes is displayed here: https://plus.google.com/101260755580272499158/posts/YyH9tDfXmo4?pid=6212661280373656642&oid=101260755580272499158&authkey=CJjXjJ2NrsLGWw. Essentially the Modified By looks like it is displaying the user's email and such. As far as the Modified Date it is displaying the time 5hrs ahead. Could you please assist? Also not sure how to add an image to comments hence the link. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get the version history modified date without any time difference.

```
$web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime($Version.Created)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same time zone conversion for file created or file modified date. 
If you use, you will get -4 to -6hrs difference.